# Using Postgresql/PostGIS/Pgrouting in PYQGIS Processing Scripts

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, postgresql

I have started exploring PYQGIS scripts and learning writing PYQGIS user scripts in python.

1. I want to use pgsql/postgis/postgresql in the script. Please suggest
2. Also Can anyone suggest That the script starts with a double Python comment symbol (##) and have the following structure

> [parameter_name]=[parameter_type] [optional_values]

Can the **parameter_type** be a database connection  So once the script is executed the pop window ask for the connection with the database etc.

3. How can one use pgrouting algorithms inside scripts.

Comment: Please take the [tour] which will explain how to ask a single, clear question.